# Handle JSON response that could be list or custom object with Moshi

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi

I am new to Moshi and looking for a way to setup a Moshi adapter with dagger 2 to automatically create a custom Object or List based on the JSON response.

The API can return either of the following 2 responses:

```
[{
    "item_type": "xyz",
    "items": [{
            "name": "foo",
            "age": 22
        },
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "age": 32
        }
    ]
}]
```

or

```
[{
    "name": "foo",
    "age": 22
},
{
    "name": "bar",
    "age": 32
}]
```

I looked at [Moshi Determine if JSON is array or single object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165604/moshi-determine-if-json-is-array-or-single-object/49204281) for reference but in my use case the whole response JSON object has a different structure. Also, Since I am using dagger2 for dependency injection, I am not sure how and where to add the adapter as my Network module which providesMoshi is pretty generic and I won't need this custom adapter for other API's.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMoshi(): Moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(Date::class.java, Rfc3339DateJsonAdapter().nullSafe())
        .build()
```

Comment: Are they different for the same endpoint or are the endpoints also different? What I'm trying to ask is, why not create different models?